# display: -webkit-box; not working in Sass

Tags: css, sass

Here is my code In Scss file:

```
@mixin kit($rows: 2, $size: 100%) { 
    display: -webkit-box; 
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical; 
    -webkit-line-clamp: $rows; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    width: $size;
    max-width: $size;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

In other Scss file

```
@include kit;
```

In Css compiled file:

```
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 1.8rem;
line-height: 1.4;
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-line-clamp: 2;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
width: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

```
-webkit-line-clamp text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

These properties do not work in Chrome,I've checked these properties on "can i use" website. Them are valid.Please, Help me!

Comment: Try to use `line-clamp: 2;` instead of `-webkit-line-clamp: 2;` (as far as I understood the [can-i-use entry](https://caniuse.com/css-line-clamp) the `display: -webkit-box` can only be used with `line-clamp` and `-webkit-line-clamp` doesn't exist)

Comment: It's doesn't work in SASS. Thank you for answer @Martin